# combobox itemssource binding issue

Tags: wpf, mvvm, binding, combobox

In a MVVM WPF application, I have a master-detail View that is used to manage Alarms. In the AlarmDetails View I have several properties that are set through ComboBox controls. One of those is the Alarm's Source, and those sources can be changed in another View (SourcesView), thus changing the combobox content in the AlarmDetailsView.

The way the data flows is relatively straightforward

1. A source is added to the collection in SourcesView
2. A message is sent from SourcesView and is received by all AlarmDetailsViewModel
3. The Sources collection in each AlarmDetailsViewModel is changed accordingly and since it is an ObservableCollection it notifies each binding targets of the change
4. The AlarmDetailsView has its DataContext set to a selected AlarmDetailsViewModel, thus the ItemsSource property of its Sources ComboBox is updated (I see it using a dummy converter, in debug I can see the updated collection being passed to ItemsSource, and it contains the newly added item)
5. After all this happened, when I navigate to the AlarmsView/AlarmDetailsView Tab, the items in the Sources ComboBox do not contain the new item.
6. When I select a new Alarm in the master list and I select the original one back, the combobox displays the new item just fine (when i select an item in the master list, the DataContext property of the AlarmDetailsView gets updated).

I am at a loss with this, I have been poundering this for a while.

Anyone have an idea? Any debugging suggestions?

Thanks,

Alex

EDIT: The ComboBox that does not update is located within the AlarmDetailsView, which means that it is used to set a property of the Alarm object (its Source, namely). Hope this helps.

EDIT 2: In addition to the answer below, another solution was to use an ObservableCollection instead of a List. For some reason, raising a PropertyChange event on the List (as described above) triggered the ComboBox to refresh its ItemsSource, but not to add the new items to its drop-down. Using the ObservableCollection, there is not need to raise the propertychange event since it manages it all by itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

** EDIT **

Ugly solution but worked for me if someone has a better solution please share :)

Emptied the collection, notified the GUI, added the real collection notified to gui

Comment: Doesn't work either. What bothers me is that I can see the actual ComboBox's collection being updated through the Converter that I added to the binding. When the collection changes the Converter is called and the object that goes through (the ItemsSource collection) contains the new item. However it doesn't show in the drop-down until I change the selected Alarm in the Master list.

Comment: hmm i've had that problem as well. Made a hack to fix it.... Emptied the collection, notified the GUI, added the real collection notified to gui... ugly as hell but worked for me

Comment: However ugly that is, it IS working. If you publish it as an answer instead of a comment, I will mark it as the answer. (unless someone provides a real solution, which would benefit both of us! :-) )

Answer (score 0):

Try using CollectionViewSource to handle your Master/Detail bindings.

Heres an example

```
<Window.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="data" Source="{Binding}" />
<Window.Resources>

DataContext="{Binding CurrentItem, Source={StaticResource data}}"
```

Comment: Do you mean binding the ItemsSource property of the ComboBox to a CollectionViewSource instead of binding it directly to the ViewModel's ObservableCollection or you mean binding the DataContext of the DetailsView to the currentitem of the MasterView items collection (it looks like the second choice)? I tried it (the DataContext option) with no success.

Comment: Bind the CollectionViewSource to your master collection in your ViewModel. Bind your master ItemsControl (ComboBox) to your CollectionViewSource. Bind your details controls to the CurrentItem property of your CollectionViewSource. Also make sure your ItemsControl has IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"

Comment: Ok I realize that my explanations might not have been totally clear. The faulty ComboBox is located within the DetailsView (it sets one of the details properties). It isn't a ComboBox that selects which DetailsView to show.